# How to install the wget package on AIX server 7.1 without having a local repository?

Tags: software-installation, wget, aix

I have remote access to my AIX 7.1 server. It has no local repository.

It has internet access but I cannot use `wget` command in this machine as the `wget` package is not installed. I downloaded a tar file from the internet and transferred it to this AIX machine. But while doing `./configure`, it asks for a gcc compiler, which is also not installed.

I tried to install by downloading the rpm package as well, but since `wget` has many dependencies, I cannot install through rpm package.

Is there any way that I can install this `wget` package by automatically downloading the required dependencies from the internet?

Comment: Have you used this repository? http://www.perzl.org/aix/

Comment: i haven't used that repository. can you please explain me a little more about this? can i download and install packages via shell itself?  like in this case i want to install wget. how can i do that?

Comment: They are repositories of open source binaries for AIX (already compiled). Unfortunately I have not used AIX for almost 2 decades now, and cant give you a hand on the specifics.

Comment: Where did you get the wget rpm from?

Comment: https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/ should work

Comment: Just for completeness, the easiest thing to also obtain all required packages would be from Bull Freeware, they enable you to easily obtain a .zip archive with all the required packages. Check e.g. http://www.bullfreeware.com/affichage.php?id=3503 for their latest wget package, you can see all the dependencies in the lower left and you can download them all together. They are also usually more current compared to the packages from the IBM linux toolbox. But you can not directly use that as an actual "repository" to directly download via shell.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: manually download and transfer the following RPMs from the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html) site:

- bash
- gettext
- info
- libiconv
- wget

... and copy them to their own directory and install them in one command:

```
sudo rpm -i bash*.rpm gettext*.rpm info*.rpm libiconv*.rpm wget*.rpm
```

I used a separate directory and wildcards in order to pick up any version of the RPM, to keep the answer flexible. You'll have specific versions of each RPM.

Option 2: (**untested**) download and use the [yum.sh script](http://ftp.software.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/yum.sh) to "download and install rpm.rte and all the packages needed for yum" and then simply `yum install wget` (**untested**).