# Alternatives to cURL/wget for remote API calls

Tags: curl, wget, aix

I'm on IBM AIX 7.1 where cURL and wget are not available. Also, I'm not in a position to install either.

Are there alternatives that would be available that would enable remote API calls using GET/POST?

Comment: lynx, w3m... At worst case scenario you can use netcat and write GET/POST by hand. (Btw. i don't understand why you can't compile a binary as user.)

Comment: `perl` -- `use LWP`

Comment: Of course! Perl... and I just thought of Python. I knew there was options, just never associated these for this type of task.

Comment: Uhh.. Wget will compile on AIX, without problems. And I'm pretty sure curl will to. What is the problem?

Comment: Essentially, not my server, unsure if I can do this with my permissions and it's not something I'm used to. I usually just run apt-get when on my own Ubuntu servers :/. Might be worth while to check I suppose.

Comment: Ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME` and got `configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`. So, no compiler on this system.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus: Look at this SE thread. Seems to have a similar problem as you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362981/how-to-install-wget-package-on-aix-server-7-1-without-having-local-repository

Comment: I really think at least some of the comments both here and in the linked question should be answers, not comments. Even if they are link-only, they would be valuable to anyone with the same problem. And as comments are not guaranteed to persist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since perl is installed by default in AIX, you could use the HTTP and LWP modules; an example, from https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod#POST, is:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = POST 'https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html',
              [ Status => 'Active', Name => 'libwww-perl' ];

print $ua->request($req)->as_string;
```